# How to import private key on testnet and verify balance of wallet?

Tags: testnet, private-key-import

I have a [python library](https://github.com/primal100/pybitcointools) to create wallets and play around with private key generation and stuff like that.

But i can't find any service / wallet - preferably online - where i could import my generated testnet-private-key and check the balance...

I can get coins thru [Testnet Faucet](https://testnet.manu.backend.hamburg/faucet) and see the balance of an address on testnet via [Blockcypher](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/) but where can i test importing private keys on the testnet?

EDIT: I don't really want to download the whole blockchain so some online service would really be great!

Comment: You shouldn't be importing private keys into any service to check balances. You should calculate the address locally, and then query explorer APIs for the balance.

Comment: i rephrased my question here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/76398/how-to-recover-wallet-by-importing-private-key-on-testnet any chance you could answer me there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote [this](https://github.com/mcdallas/cryptotools) python library since pybitcointools is no longer supported. You can check testnet balances like this (it pulls data from blockchain.info)

```
import os
os.environ['CRYPTOTOOLS_NETWORK'] = 'test'

from btctools import Address

address = Address('n2NGrooSecJaiD6ssp4YqFoj9eZ7GrCJ66')

>>> address.balance()
0.55
```

Comment: i rephrased my question here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/76398/how-to-recover-wallet-by-importing-private-key-on-testnet any chance you could answer me there?